# Limiting distribution of the first order statistic of a general distribution

Tags: self-study, convergence, asymptotics, order-statistics

Let $Z_i,Z_2,\ldots$ be IID Random Variables with density $f$. Suppose that $P(Z_i>0)=1$ and that $\lambda=\lim_{x \to 0+} f(x)>0$. How can I show that $X_n=n \times \min\{Z_i\}$ has a limiting exponential distribution with mean$1/\lambda$?

I know that the CDF of the first order Statistic is for $t>0$

$$F_{min \{ Z_i \}} (t)= 1- \left[ 1-F(t) \right]^{n}$$

Convergence in distribution requires that $F_n (t) \to F(t)$ for some distribution function $F$ but I cannot quite take the limit of the above, with $t$ replaced by $x/n$, as the distribution is not known. I guess I have to insert the second piece of information somewhere but I do not recognise where.

Could you please give me a hint or two?

Thank you.

Comment: One approach is to apply the [Fisher-Tippett-Gnedenko theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Tippett%E2%80%93Gnedenko_theorem) to $-Z_i$.

Comment: @whuber Thank you, I didn't even know that such thing existed. I wonder though whether a simpler way exists as my knowledge does not stretch that far yet.

Comment: I believe a study of that theorem will pay off here, if only to suggest that what you are trying to prove might not be true--or at least requires some strong additional assumptions about $F$.

Comment: @whuber Okay, thank you. For the record, this is a question that comes from L. Wasserman's All of Statistics page 105,exercise 13 http://research.rmutp.ac.th/research/A%20Concise%20Course%20in%20Statistical%20Inference.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the reference: in reading it I see I overlooked the assumption that the limiting value of the density at zero is strictly positive: that's a crucial assumption. Intuitively, it tells you that the distribution of the minimum of a very large number of independent variables will be controlled by the value of $f$ near $0$. So one way to appreciate this problem would be to replace $F$ by, say, a *uniform* distribution, which would have to be U$(0,1/\lambda)$. You can compute the distribution of $X_n$ exactly in this case: what is it and what is its limit as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: @whuber Thank you very much. It is easy to seen that $\lim_{n \to \infty} 1-\left[1-\frac{\lambda x}{n} \right]^n $ is $1-e^{\lambda x}$, the CDF of an exponential distribution with mean $1/\lambda$. If you would not mind, could you explain a bit more how that bound implies that F could be replaced with a uniform distribution? I think I am close to getting it. Thanks again.

Comment: John, I think I have solved this. Hint: Calculate the density of $X_n$, you will get a product. Consider product of the limits. For the one, use the information given to you. For the second try to "see" the limit representation of the base of the natural logarithms. Let me know if you want me to post the answer.

Comment: Thank you @AlecosPapadopoulos. You can certainly post an answer, if you like so I can mark it as the correct one. My sole objection is that the limit we are taking in this case is the limit of a pdf and I do not think we are supposed to do that,in fact I have seen many counterexamples of this practice. Are we not supposed to examine CDF's only?

Comment: Well, then you can do it directly on the cdf of $X_n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(The answer has been reworked to respond to OP's and whuber's comments).*

The complementary cdf of $X$ is

$$G_n(x) = \left[1-F_Z\left(x/n\right)\right]^{n}$$

To prove that asymptotically $X$ follows an exponential distribution, we need to show that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}G_n(x)= e^{-\lambda x}$$

Consider

$$F_Z\left(x/n\right) = \int_0^{x/n}f(t)dt $$

By the properties of the integral, we have

$$\int_0^{x/n}f(t)dt  = \frac 1n\int_0^{x}f(t/n)dt$$

Define 
$$h_n(w) =  \left(1+\frac {w}{n}\right)^{n}, \qquad \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}h_n(w) =  e^w=h(w), \;\; w \in \mathbb R$$

and

$$g_n(x) = -\int_0^{x}f(t/n)dt,\;\;\; -\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}g_n(x) = -\int_0^{x}f(0)dt = -\lambda x = g(x), \;\;x \in \mathbb R_+$$

(To respond to a question by the OP, we can take the limit inside the integral. First note that $n\geq 1$, and we do *not* send $x$ to infinity. So the argument of $f$ does not explode. So even if it were the case that $f(\infty) \rightarrow \infty$, we do not need to consider this case here. Then, since also $f(0)$ is finite by assumption, $f$ is bounded and dominated convergence holds).

With these definitions we can write

$$G_n(x) = h_n(g_n(x))$$

and the question is

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}h_n(g_n(x)) =?\;\; h(g(x)) = e^{-\lambda x},\;\;x \in \mathbb R_+$$

The limit of a composition of function-sequences does not in general equal the composition of their limits (which is what whuber has essentially pointed out in his comment). But this equality will hold if
$(i)$ $h_n$ converges uniformly to $h$ (it does-convergence to $e^w$ is uniform)
$(ii)$ the limit of $h_n$ is a continuous function (it is)
$(iii)$ the functions $g_n(x)$ map $\mathbb R_+$ to $\mathbb R$ (namely, they map their domain into the set where $h_n$ converges -they do).

So the above equality holds and we have proven what we needed to prove.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you. Are we in the clear about moving the limit inside the integral?

Comment: There is a subtle issue that seems not to be justified in this demonstration: when taking the limits, the *same* $n$ is involved in the limit of the integrals and the limit of the powers (the antepenultimate and penultimate lines, respectively): without specific analysis, *you cannot take those limits separately*. (It was the consideration of this point that originally caused me to present a slightly longer answer.)

Comment: @whuber whenever you have some time, I would appreciate if you could have a look at my re-worked answer - I tried to respond to your comment.

Comment: You have definitely answered my question, thank you.

Comment: Alecos if you would not mind, could I get your opinion on an Analysis text? Preferably one that you think can help us in doing Statistics, like your answer above.

Comment: I believe you can seriously consider http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Mathematical-Analysis-Economic-Econometrics/dp/0691118671

Answer (score 4):

To prove convergence in distribution we need to show that the complementary distribution of $X_n$, written $G_n$ where $G_n(x)=\Pr(X_n\gt x)$, gets close to an exponential function for $n$ sufficiently large.  To this end, let $t\gt 0$ be an arbitrary point at which to evaluate $G_n(t)$.  Note that the independence of the $Z_i$ implies

$$G_n(t) = \left(1 - F\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)\right)^n = \left(1 - \lambda\frac{t}{n} + \left[\lambda\frac{t}{n} -  F\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)\right]\right)^n.$$

The term in square brackets is the problem--if it weren't there the limit would obviously be exponential--so we will use the only information available to us to estimate it and hope that it's very small for large $n$.  The existence of the limit

$$\lambda = {\lim}_{x\to 0^{+}} f\left(x\right)$$

implies

$$\left|\lambda\frac{t}{n} - F\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)\right| = \left|\int_0^{t/n} (\lambda - f(u)) du\right| \le \frac{t}{n}\sup_{0\le u\le t/n}\left(|\lambda - f(u)|\right) = \frac{t}{n}\varepsilon(n)$$

for some function $\varepsilon$ that approaches $0$ for large arguments.  Substitute this into the foregoing and assume $n$ is so large that $F\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)\lt 1$, so that we may take logarithms, and use the Taylor series of the logarithm near $1$ to estimate

$$\eqalign{
\log(G(t))=n\log\left(1 - F\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)\right) &= n\log\left(1 - \lambda\frac{t}{n} + \left[\lambda\frac{t}{n} -  F\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)\right]\right) \\
&= n\log\left(1 - \left(\lambda-\varepsilon(n)\right)\frac{t}{n}\right) \\
&= -\left(\lambda-\varepsilon(n)\right)t + \left[(\lambda - \varepsilon(n))t\right]^2O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).
}$$

Clearly (applying theorems about the limits of products and sums of continuous functions) this has a limit as $n\to \infty$ and it equals $-\lambda t$, showing that $G(t)=\exp(\log(G(t))$ has the limiting value $\exp(-\lambda t)$, QED.

Comment: Referring to the question's comment thread, when $n$ is very large so that $t/n$ is very small (but positive), we can characterize $\lambda\frac{t}{n} -  F\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)$ as the discrepancy between $F$ and a Uniform$(\lambda)$ distribution near $0$.  Thus this argument is simply a semi-rigorous restatement of the intuition expressed in those comments. (For even more rigor one would write a full epsilon-delta limiting argument, but it should now be obvious how that proof would go.)

Comment: Thank you very much both for your answer and for your comments.