# Does the central limit theorem apply to these probability density functions?

Tags: density-function, central-limit-theorem

Let's say you have n uniform random variables from 0 to 1. The distribution of the average of these variables approaches normal with increasing n according to the central limit theorem. What if however, instead of all the variables being random, one of them was guaranteed to be 0, and one of them was guaranteed to be 1. This would arise in the following case: Let's say you have n=7 randomly generated numbers from 0 to 1 and they are, from smallest to largest, [.1419 .1576 .4854 .8003 .9572 .9649 .9706]. If you were to subtract the smallest number from all of the numbers and then divide all the numbers by the new maximum you would end up with [0 .0189 .4145 .7945 .9838 .9931 1]. In this way you have a set of n numbers where n-2 of them are random and the other two are guaranteed to be 0 and 1. I would like to know whether the central limit theorem still applies to numbers generated in this way. By visual inspection using MATLAB, it actually appears to approach normal quicker than when the numbers are all random, but I would like a mathematical reason as to why, especially considering that the central limit theorem states that all the numbers must be random.

Comment: Note that your $n-2$ random numbers are also *correlated* and they do not necessarily have uniform distributions.  Note, too, that any constant can be viewed as a random variable (whose value equals that constant everywhere), so that's not a problem.

Comment: When you say "does the central limit theorem apply" ... but it's not clear what you're trying to apply it to. Note that the central limit theorem talks about the distribution of standardized averages when $\lim_{n\to\infty}$, not something you might notice when $n=7$. What is the limiting process you're considering?

Comment: I just picked n=7 as an example to demonstrate how I was manipulating the data i.e. subtracting the minimum and dividing through by the new maximum. When I say "does the central limit theorem apply" I'm asking if the pdf converges to normal with increasing n.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Denote $X_i, i=1,...,n$ the $U(0,1)$ independent RVs. The transformation described by the OP is (using the usual notation for order statistics),

$$Z_i = \frac {X_i-X_{n,(1)}}{X_{n,(n)}-X_{n,(1)}} = R_n^{-1}\cdot (X_i-X_{n,(1)})$$

where the double index in the minimum and maximum order statistic serve to remind us that they are functions of $n$. $R_n$ is the range of the untransformed sample.

We want to consider

$$\frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^nZ_i \equiv \bar Z_n = R_n^{-1}\frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^nX_i - R_n^{-1}X_{n,(1)}$$

We have that

$$R_n^{-1} \xrightarrow{p} 1,\;\;\; \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^nX_i \xrightarrow{p} \frac 12,\;\; X_{n,(1)}\xrightarrow{p} 0$$

So in all, applying Slutsky's lemma,

$$\bar Z_n \xrightarrow{p} \frac 12 = \text{plim} \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^nX_i \equiv \text{plim}\bar X_n$$

So the sample average of the transformed sample is also a consistent estimator of the common expected value of the $X$'s.  Note that $\text{Var}(\bar X_n) = \frac 1{12n}$

Then, consider the manipulation

$$\sqrt{12n}\left(\bar Z_n - \frac 12\right) = \\R_n^{-1}\cdot \sqrt{12n}\left(\bar X_n - \frac 12 \right)  +\sqrt{12n}\left(\frac 12R_n^{-1} -\frac 12\right) -\sqrt{12n}R_n^{-1}X_{n,(1)}$$

We examine each of the three components in turn:

**A)** By the **CLT** we have that  $\sqrt{12n}\left(\bar X_n - \frac 12 \right) \xrightarrow{d}\mathcal N (0,1)$. Since also $R_n^{-1} \xrightarrow{p} 1$, then by Slutsky the first term converges in distribution to $\mathcal N (0,1)$.

**B)** We can write

$$\sqrt{12n}\left(\frac 12R_n^{-1} -\frac 12\right) = \sqrt{3}\left(\frac {n(1-R_n)}{\sqrt nR_n}\right)$$

In [Dasgupta 2008](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/probability/book/978-0-387-75970-8) ch. 8 p. 108 Example 8.12, one can find for the sample range from an i.i.d. sample of $U(0,1)$ uniforms that $n(1-R_n) \xrightarrow{d} \frac 12 \mathcal \chi^2(4)$). So the numerator above converges while the denominator goes to infinity. So the whole term goes to zero.

**C)** We know that the minimum order statistic from a sample of non-negative random variables, needs to be scaled by $n$ in order to converge in distribution ([see this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102691/limiting-distribution-of-the-first-order-statistic-of-a-general-distribution/102731#102731)). In other words convergence is "fast", and scaling the third term only by $\sqrt n$ doesn't cut it. Therefore we have that  $\sqrt{12n}R_n^{-1}X_{n,(1)} \rightarrow0$.

So, we conclude that

$$\sqrt{12n}\left(\bar Z_n - \frac 12\right) \xrightarrow{d} \mathcal N(0,1)$$

as does $\bar X_n$, for the same shifting and scaling.

Answer (score -2):

Say your sample is $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, you are looking at the random variable

$$z = \frac{\bar{x} - \min_i x_i}{\max_i x_i - \min_i x_i}$$

In the case of the uniform distribution, $z$ converges almost surely to $\bar{x}$, and since $\bar{x}$ converges in distribution to a normal distribution, so does $z$.

Comment: Suppose instead the $X_i$ were iid exponential, shifted to the left by $1$ to center them at zero.  Then the numerator of $z$ would converge a.s. to $1$ while the denominator would diverge a.s., making $z$ converge to a *constant* $0$ rather than a normal distribution.  It would therefore seem that your reasoning is not sufficient to demonstrate the conclusion.

Comment: You said uniform.

Comment: I am only addressing the logic of your answer, Arthur. By applying *exactly your reasoning* to this exponential variable I have obtained a contradiction: the distribution of $z$ in the exponential case cannot both be $0$ and Normal (as your post would ask us to believe).  Therefore, even though your *conclusion* is correct, it cannot be correct by virtue of the reasons you have offered.

Comment: My answer says very clearly: in the case of the uniform distribution.