# how to prove if central limit theorem would apply to a process?

Tags: central-limit-theorem

I'm very new to stats so apologies in advance for not using the right language and terms.

I have just learned about the central limits thm can show up in places other than taking a sample distribution of mean, but in cases where a large number of factors all contribute to an outcome. An example is the chest-size measurement: https://www.britannica.com/science/central-limit-theorem

To see this for myself, I wrote some "arbitrary" function where a large number of random factors contribute (deterministically) to an outcome, code below:

```
def sample_number():
    N = 1234
    As = np.random.rand(N)
    Bs = np.random.rand(N)

    ret = 0
    for i in range(N):
        if As[i] > 0.1:
            ret += Bs[i] / As[i]
        else:
            ret += np.log(0.01 + As[i] ** Bs[i])

    return ret
```

lo and behold, as N becomes bigger, the distribution of the random variable "sample_number" looks more and more like a normal distribution once plotted.

with N = 4
[image]

with N = 400
[image]

however this really isn't a proof, so I'm looking for if there's some general statement one can make about these kinds of problems, i.e. some function class (polynomials of finite degrees, or neural networks) mapping N random variables to a single numerical outcome, in such a way that it "uses" all the information of these N random variables (perhaps we can demand that the outcome has nonzero mutual information to any individual r.v.) will result in a normal distribution as N goes to infinity.

the closest thread is this one: [Does the central limit theorem apply to these probability density functions?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122094/does-the-central-limit-theorem-apply-to-these-probability-density-functions), but I am not sure if the same analysis will work for the code I have wrote, as I purposefully made it annoying to manipulate analytically.

thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't have an intermediate or advance level probability or math stat book at hand you can read about central limit theorems on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem).. Many tests show a proof (often using moment generating functions) of the convergence of standardized means or sums of samples of size $n\rightarrow\infty$ to standard normal provided that $Var(X_i) = \sigma^2$ is finite. // However, as you have seen, an intuitive view can be obtained by simulation of means of large samples, showing that they have nearly-normal distributions.

Comment: @BruceET I guess my experiment was done kind of badly, I don't mean to limit the function class as "sums of samples" but rather a broader class of functions, for instance maybe multiplying them or taking the max? would CLT still hold?

Comment: Maybe add mods of the question as an edit to the post? But generally, CLT are for sums/means ... if you are interested in max you will need other results