# Distribution of $S = \min\{ X_1, ..., X_n\}$ and $c$ s.t. $E(c\hat{\theta}) = \theta$

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, unbiased-estimator

## **Warning**

The question is the third and last part of [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/602961/mle-of-the-pareto-parameter-theta-and-unbiasedness).

## **Exercise**

Let $X \thicksim Pa(\lambda,\theta)$ with density function:
$ f(x; \theta, \lambda) = \frac{\lambda \theta^{\lambda}}{x^{\lambda+1}} $
where $x \geq \theta$, $\lambda >0$ and $\theta > 0$.

The CDF is $ F(x) = 1 - \left( \frac{\theta}{x} \right)^{\lambda} $

Let $\lambda $ known. Find the distribution of $S$ and establish if exists an unbiased estimator of $\theta$  in the class of estimators $c \cdot S$ where $c$ is an appropriate constant.

## **Try**

The density and the CDF of $S = \min\{ X_1, ..., X_n \}$ are:

- $F_S(x) = 1 - \left( \frac{\theta}{x} \right)^{n\lambda}$
- $f_S(x) = \frac{n\lambda \theta^{\lambda}}{x^{\lambda+1}} \left( \frac{\theta}{x} \right)^{\lambda(n-1)} = \frac{n\lambda \theta^{n\lambda}}{x^{n\lambda+1}} $

The MLE estimator of the $X$ is the minimum: $\hat{\theta} = x_{(1)} = \min\{x_1, ..., x_n\}$.

The distribution of $S$ is the following:
$$
F_S(x) = P(X_{(1)} \leq x) = 1 - P(X_{(1)} > x)
$$

Since the $X_i$ are i.i.d.,
$$
\begin{align}
F_S(x) & = 1 - P(min(X_1, ..., X_n) > x) \\
& = 1 - P(X_i > x, \qquad i = 1, ..., n) \\
& = 1 - P\left[ (X_1 > x) \cap (X_2 > x) \cap ... \cap (X_n > x) \right] \\
& = 1 - P\left[ (X_1 > x) \cdot (X_2 > x) \cdots (X_n > x) \right] \\
& = 1 - \left[ (1 - F_{X_1}(x)) \cdot (1 - F_{X_2}(x)) \cdots (1 - F_{X_n}(x)) \right] \\
& = 1 - \left[ (1 - F_X(x)) \cdot (1 - F_X(x)) \cdots (1 - F_X(x)) \right] \\
& = 1 - \left[ 1 - F_X(x) \right]^n \\
\end{align}
$$

Since $F_X(x) = 1 - (\theta/x)^{\lambda}$,
$$
F_S(x) = 1 - \left[1 - 1 + (\theta/x)^{\lambda} \right]^n = 1 - \left( \frac{\theta}{x} \right)^{n\lambda}
$$

The statistic $S \thicksim Pa(n\lambda,\theta)$.

For the next point I have found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b_Yb52U3PU8) that explains it. I set the following equation: $ E(c\hat{\theta}) = \theta $, hence:
$$
\int^{+\infty}_{\theta} c\hat{\theta}f(\theta)dx
$$

Let's solve the integral before:
$$
\int^{+\infty}_{\theta} c\hat{\theta}f(\theta)dx  = \int^{+\infty}_{\theta} cx\frac{n\lambda \theta^{n\lambda}}{x^{n\lambda+1}}dx = c\theta \left( \frac{n\lambda }{n\lambda-1} \right) 
$$

Finally:
$$
c\theta \left( \frac{n\lambda }{n\lambda-1} \right)  = \theta
$$

$$
c = \left( \frac{n\lambda -1}{n\lambda} \right) 
$$

If I have missed anything else, please report it to me immediately.

Comment: Your algebra in the "Try" section is incorrect.  Use the laws of probability to find the distribution of the minimum in terms of the distribution of the variables.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129145/. It helps to work in terms of the survival function (*aka* complementary CDF). See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102691 for examples.  Search our site for [many applications and generalizations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/547710/deriving-the-pdf-of-the-kth-order-statistic-from-the-cdf/547717#547717).

Comment: @whuber I have tried to adjust the algebra. Is it right?

Comment: A quick glance indicates you have the ideas correct now.

Comment: @whuber Thank you. I'm glad to have resolved this issue too, refining the style a bit. Again, I thank you for your helpfulness.